# How to retrieve attributes of class passed in the view inside the mixin used by this view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an AxiliarClass with attributes and i pass it to the view as an attribute. I have a mixin that i use in the view but i need to get the attributes from the AuxiliarClass inside the mixin, how can in do it.

```
class AuxiliarClass:
    extra_fields=[{"key": "value"}]


class TurmaListCreateView(MytMixin, generics.CreateAPIView):

    model=MyModel
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer  
    extra_fields_class=AuxiliarClass

class MytMixin():
    
     extra_fields_class=None
     
     def get_queryset(self):
        
        print("i need to access the the extra_fields array here and the values inside it")
```

I want to be able to acess the values inside the extra_fields array inside the get_queryset funtion in Mymixin

I tried this, but im not able to see the array and i dont know how to get it

```
class MytMixin():
    
     extra_fields_class=None
     
     def get_queryset(self):
        
        print(self.extra_fields_class.__dict__.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
class MytMixin():

 extra_fields_class=None
 
 def get_queryset(self):
    extra = self.extra_fields_class()
    print(extra.extra_fields)
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I get this error: module 'core.AuxiliarClass' has no attribute 'extra_fields'

Comment: Use condition inside get_queryset  `if self.extra_fields_class: extra = self.extra_fields_class()`